# current date as default in jQuery Mobile form

Tags: jquery, html, default-value, jquery-mobile

I'm creating an app to capture memories using jQuery Mobile. I have a form to fill out a new memory and save it. One of the fields is the date of the event. This field needs to be editable as an input so that if they are putting in a past memory they can do so, but I wanted to add the default date to populate with the current date when the user opens the app. Below is what I have so far, but I haven't been able to find anything that lets me pre-fill that input with the current date.

HTML

```
<!-- Date -->
<div data-role=fieldcontain>
    <label for=date>Date</label>
<input type=date name=date id=date class="date required" />
<!-- <p>Date format goes here</p> -->
</div><!-- /Date -->
```

JavaScript

```
$('#addItem').on('pageinit', function(){

var myForm = $('#newMemForm'),
    errorLink = $('#errorLink'),
    currentTime = new Date();



    myForm.validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    errorLink.click();
    html = '';
    for(key in validator.submitted){
        var label = $('label[for^="'+ key +'"]').not('[generated]');
        var legend = label.closest('fildset').find('.ui-controlgroup-lable');
        var fieldName = legend.length ? legend.text() : label.text();
        html += '<li>'+ fieldName +'</li>';
    }
    $("#errorLink ul").html(html);
    },
        submitHandler: function() {
        var data = myForm.serializeArray();
        storeData(data);
        }
});

$("#date").value(currentTime);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to set a `value` inside your `<input>` tag like so.

```
var currentTime = new Date();

$("#date").val(currentTime);
```

Comment: And this should be in my main.js file?

Comment: Please look at my edited question...This is what I have in my .js file and it is causing the page not to load? Looks like it loads an infinite loop. It works fine when date value is not there

Comment: You're missing a `,` in the `var` declaration.

Comment: Even with that fix, it still isn't working. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Oops.  It's not value() it's `.val(),`. Sorry about that.

Comment: I did notice in my html I didn't have the id as a sting...but it still is not working. I even tried putting a generic value directly in the html, and when inspecting it with chrome dev tools when jQuery parses the info it removed the value attribute...I also `console.log`'ed the `new Date();` and it showed as `Mon May 27 2013 02:50:30 GMT-0400 (EDT)` when I'm only looking for `May 27 2013` (not sure if that makes a difference)